# Is it possible to pass null reference to Init view model?

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I have this call on one view model

```
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(
    new MyParams { ... }
);
```

On MyViewModel I have this `Init` method which works perfect

```
public void Init(MyParams params)
{
    if (params != null)
    {
        // some logic
    }
    else 
    {
        // some other logic
    }
}
```

On another view model I have

```
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>();
```

I expect to receive null on `MyViewModel` init method, instead of that I get an instance of 'MyParams'. That's generating problems since I have specific logic to handle the call with no parameters

I have custom presenter logic that might responsible for this, but at first sight I couldn't identify any custom logic as responsible. Is this the standard behavior for complex params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no there isn't a way to pass *null* using a parameters object.

The reason is that when Mvx creates the ViewModel and attempts to call the `Init` method, it will first convert your object instance into a simple dictionary (key/value pairs). If you use the no arg version, then it creates an empty dictionary. At this point, it creates an `MvxBundle` which includes the dictionary.

When Mvx is finally ready to call your `Init` method, it takes this dictionary and attempts to create an actual object.

It's this method that creates the instance to pass to `Init`.

`MvxSimplePropertyDictionaryExtensionMethods.Read()`

https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/8a824c797747f74716fc64c2fd0e8765c29b16ab/MvvmCross/Core/Core/Platform/MvxSimplePropertyDictionaryExtensionMethods.cs#L54-L72

```cs
public static object Read(this IDictionary<string, string> data, Type type)
{
    var t = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    var propertyList =
        type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy).Where(p => p.CanWrite);

    foreach (var propertyInfo in propertyList)
    {
        string textValue;
        if (!data.TryGetValue(propertyInfo.Name, out textValue))
            continue;

        var typedValue = MvxSingletonCache.Instance.Parser.ReadValue(textValue, propertyInfo.PropertyType,
                                                                     propertyInfo.Name);
        propertyInfo.SetValue(t, typedValue, new object[0]);
    }

    return t;
}
```

Notice how it calls `Activator.CreateInstance(type)` which will always return an instance.

So that is why you'll never get an *null* value in `Init`.

My recommendation is to simply add a property to your `MyParams` object and set that in your no-arg version. Then in `Init` you can check the property to determine what to do.

Something like:

```cs
ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(new MyParams { HasNoParams = true });

public void Init(MyParams myParams)
{
    if (myParams.HasNoParams)
    {
        // do null flow here
    }
    else 
    {
        // do non-null flow here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dictionary< TKey, TValue> as your params.